# react js show some content on first page only but all content show on page url like seemore

Tags: reactjs

I am using react js. I am going to develop a react js app. in this app I have 12 cards (services of the company) I develop it successfully but I want 6 cards to show on the home page and all cards show on the services page. How does it? Thank you

Comment: try using .filter() on array of cards on your homepage to show only a selection of cards

Comment: Thank you. Can you share about this sample code please